# Radius of Convergence Involving Hyperbolic Tangent (tanh)

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, hyperbolic-functions

For the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6^n \tanh(n^2) \, z^n, 
$$
the radius of convergence is
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} 
\left| 
\frac{6^n \tanh(n^2)}{6^{n+1} \tanh\bigl((n+1)^2\bigr)} 
\right|
= \frac{1}{6} \lim_{n \to \infty} 
\left| 
\frac{\tanh(n^2)}{\tanh\bigl((n+1)^2\bigr)} 
\right|
$$

But this is where I get stuck: $\tanh$ asymptotes to $1$, but I'm not sure how to prove what the ratio is.  L'Hôpital's doesn't seem to accomplish anything, and I've been mucking with $\tanh$ identities and haven't come up with anything useful.

Comment: If $\tanh(n^2)$ is increasing and almost $1$ for large $n$, the limit of the ratio cannot exceed $1$, but must exceed $\tanh(n^2)$ for large $n$

Comment: Simple: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{\tanh (n^2 )}}{{\tanh ((n + 1)^2 )}} = \frac{{\mathop {\lim }_{n \to  + \infty } \tanh (n^2 )}}{{\mathop {\lim }_{n \to  + \infty } \tanh ((n + 1)^2 )}} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.
$$ You just use the rule that the limit of a ratio is the ratio of the limits (provided all the limits exist).

Comment: The sequence $\tanh(n^2)={1-e^{-2n^2}\over 1+e^{-2n^2}}$ tends to $1,$ so does the ratio as the ratio of two sequences tending to $1.$ No monotonic properties are needed.

Answer (score 1):

as stated above, the simplest answer was the limit of the ratio is equal to the ratio of the limits (barring certain cases).  Thanks!